# How to get text from modal and insert in email body?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, twitter-bootstrap

This code work fine except the `comment`: It's not insert in the body of message.

```html
<div class="modal" id="feedback">
    <form action="/feedback" method="POST">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <textarea class="input-xxlarge" name="comment" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a class="btn" type="submit" href="/feedback">Send</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

```py
class SendFeedback(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()
    comment = self.request.get('comment')
    message = mail.EmailMessage()
    message.sender = user
    message.to = 'foo@bar.com'
    message.subject = "Feedback from %s" % user
    message.body = """
            Feedback:
            %s
            """ % comment
    message.send()
    self.redirect(self.request.headers['referer'])
```

Depends on `ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data"` or `%s` or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the forms method is POST while your Handler implemented a GET method.

**edit**:

change `def get(self)` to `def post(self)`

```
class SendFeedback(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        ...
```

and the post data is:

```
data    = self.request.POST
comment = data.get('comment')
```

**edit2**

this code works:

```
form = """
<div class="modal fade" id="feedback">
    <form action="/feedback" method="POST">
        <div class="modal-header"><h3>Aiutaci a migliorare</h3></div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>un piacere sapere cosa cambiereste di Metrico</p>
                <textarea class="input-xxlarge" name="comment" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer"><input class="btn btn-inverse" type="submit"/></div>
    </form>
</div>
"""

class FormTest(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write(form)

    def post(self):
        data = self.request.POST
        comment = data.get('comment')
        body = """
Feedback:
%s
""" % comment
        self.response.out.write(body)
```

Comment: with `post` in handler I have a 405 method not allowed. With `get` work except the comment in body.

Comment: you have a method not allowed because you did implement a get method and no post. check my edit

Comment: thank you, but with your fix still get a 405.
with `def get(self)` instead receive a mail with `None` in the body. a progress, thanks to `self.request.POST`

Comment: can you please post your full traceback? if you change to POST you need to change form action and handler method. i think you have method='GET' in the form and def post in the handler or vice versa.

Comment: whit post in form and handler i receive:
405 Method Not Allowed
The method GET is not allowed for this resource.

whit post in form and get in the handler:
send the mail with `None` instead the comment value

Comment: i added an edit2 with a working form. i dont send a mail but it writes out the comment.